# Sending an "if-modified-since" header in the request

Tags: java, rest, api, last-modified, if-modified-since

I am new to working with the Rest API in Java. I am trying to implement `if-modified-since` request and got stuck with questions:

1. Client sends a get request and the server responds with a resource and a `Last-Modified` header. From then on, client sends a request with the `Last-Modified` in the `if-modified-since` header. Does this mean that, the first get request from client does not have a `if-modified-since` header ?
2. Would the `Last-Modified` received in the response stored in the browser for ever or should it be stored some where in the client side database to make further requests?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. No, there won't be an if-modified-since if the client does not have a cached version of the resource.
2. This is up to the client.  Browsers certainly don't cache everything indefinitely.  But in theory an arbitrary client could store the last modified timestamp wherever it needs to.